# Not able to get permission to access user contacts in Mac menu bar app

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm trying to access a user's contacts in my Mac menu bar app and have the following code. I have `Privacy - Contacts Usage Description` set in my info.plist as well. But I keep getting the following error: `Error Domain=CNErrorDomain Code=100 "Access Denied" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Access Denied, NSLocalizedFailureReason=This application has not been granted permission to access Contacts.}`

I've attached all the code below for a sample app I made that exhibits similar behavior. When I go to settings and go to Privacy & Security -> Contacts, it shows that no apps are currently requesting access to your contacts.

```
import Contacts
import SwiftUI

struct Contact {
    let id = UUID().uuidString
    let firstName: String
    let phoneNumbers: [CNLabeledValue<CNPhoneNumber>]
    let avatar: Data?
}

class ContactStore: ObservableObject {

    @Published var contacts = [Contact]()
    
    @MainActor
    func fetchContacts() async {
        let store = CNContactStore()

        switch CNContactStore.authorizationStatus(for: .contacts) {
        case .notDetermined:
            do {
                try await store.requestAccess(for: .contacts)
            } catch {
                print("ERROR initializing contact store and getting user access:", error)
            }

        case .authorized:
            contacts.removeAll()
            if CNContactStore.authorizationStatus(for: .contacts)  == .authorized {
                let request = CNContactFetchRequest(keysToFetch: [
                    CNContactGivenNameKey as CNKeyDescriptor,
                    CNContactPhoneNumbersKey as CNKeyDescriptor,
                    CNContactThumbnailImageDataKey as CNKeyDescriptor
                ])

                do {
                    try store.enumerateContacts(with: request, usingBlock: { contact, stop in
                        contacts.append(Contact(firstName: contact.givenName, phoneNumbers: contact.phoneNumbers, avatar: contact.thumbnailImageData))
                    })
                } catch {
                    print("Error enumerating over contacts:", error)
                }
            }

        default:
            print("Could not contact data")
        }
    }

}
```

App File

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct TestContactAppApp: App {
    @StateObject var contactsStore = ContactStore()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        MenuBarExtra {
            ContentView()
                .environmentObject(contactsStore)
        } label : {
            Image(systemName: "pencil.circle.fill")
        }
        .menuBarExtraStyle(.window)
    }
}
```

ContentView

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var contactStore: ContactStore
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Get contacts") {
                Task {
                    await contactStore.fetchContacts()
                }
            }
            
        }
        .padding()
        .frame(width: 100, height: 100)
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you add the part of your code when you use `ContactStore`? I just created a small app to test the permissions system in your class and it works fine.

Comment: @BenA. Currently I just have it on my main ContentView and have an .onAppear {} modifier that fetches the contacts which I print

Comment: @BenA. Could it be that it's on a macOS MenuBarExtra app?

Comment: I can help you out more if you update your post to include the code.

Comment: @BenA. Just made a sample project that exhibits similar behavior and added all the code in an edit.

Answer (score 1):

For me I had to add the capability to add read and write contact like in the screenshot below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The difference in your implementation and my implementation is how the authorization request for contacts is called. The `init` for `ContactStore` contains `try await store.requestAccess(for: .contacts)`; that is, the request happens upon initialization.

The way I had done it was by initializing `ContactStore` in the view. Before seeing your version, this was that part of the implementation:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject private var contactStore = ContactStore()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
        }.onAppear {
            contactStore.fetchContacts()
        }
    }
}
```

The initialization of `ContactStore` in the `ContentView` correctly requested authorization. In your version, you don't initialize within the `ContentView`.

I don't know the exact details of your app, so I can't make specific recommendations about your `EnvironmentalObject`, `StateObject`, etc., usage, but if you initialize your `ContactStore` class in the `ContentView`, it should work. You could also move where you request authorization.

Comment: What I'm noticing is that every time I call store.requestAccess(for: .contacts), it gives me the error I stated above and sets the CNContactStore.authorizationStatus to denied. The user doesn't get any option to enable contacts and inside of settings I'm not able to either.

Comment: Noticed that when I use WindowGroup instead of MenuBarExtra and run it on an iPhone simulator instead of Mac, it works

Answer (score 0):

Figured out that for macOS apps, you need to turn on the Address Book entitlement as well. After doing that, the user gets a notification.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/entitlements/com_apple_security_personal-information_addressbook#